# SVN copy only certain file type

Tags: svn

In my scripts, I have a point where I want to copy ONLY the .csv files from my current build over to another folder. I currently have...

```
svn copy $repoName/*.csv $targetRepo
```

But I really didn't expect that to work. However, that is essentially what I want to accomplish. Does SVN have a way to copy only certain types of files? If not, what direction could I go in to possibly do that?

(Helpful?: this is all being done through automated Perl scripts.)

Comment: Is there a way I can use Perl to check the SVN repository for .csv files, then put those all in an array and copy them individually (in a foreach)?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? On Linux, there should be a nice variant with `find . -name ...` at the beginning.

Comment: How to do this isn't hard... but I'm struggling to understand /why/ you'd want to do this.  What are you really trying to solve?  I suspect you're fighting with subversion because your build or svn layout is really odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It's a bit forceful, but it seems to work. Here is my Perl code:

```
system("svn list $repoName --depth infinity | find \".csv\" >> csvs.txt");
open FILE, "limits.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <FILE>){      
   system("svn copy".$line." $targetRepo");
}   
close FILE;
system("del /s /q csvs.txt");
```

I have simplified it a lot here, but basically it just finds all the .csv's, puts them in a list, then copies those files one by one.